# Gallery scroll invalidates whole view

Tags: android-layout, android

I have a Gallery in my layout together with an ImageView and a few TextView widgets. Unfortunately I get low scroll performance for the Gallery on a slow phones. The problem disappears when I remove the background image from the LinearLayout containing ImageView and TextView.
I overrrided the onDraw() for the whole view and checked the clip rect - it is always the whole screen. It looks like every time I scroll the gallery (and it is invalidated) the whole screen is invalidated.
Is there any way to avoid full screen redraw when I only scroll the Gallery widget?

Thanks

```
private class GalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<WeatherDisplayInfo> {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context mContext;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.gallery_item_view, mForecastData);

        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mForecastData.size();
    }

    public WeatherDisplayInfo getItem(int position) {
        return mForecastData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text_date;
        public TextView text_forecast;
        public TextView text_temperature;

        public TextView text_pressure;
        public TextView text_humidity;
        public TextView text_windspeed;

        public ImageView weather_image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;


        if(convertView == null) {

            if(position == getCount() - 1) {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.logo_view, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                // store view holder
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item_view, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.text_date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
                holder.text_forecast = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_desc);
                holder.text_temperature = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_temp);

                holder.text_pressure = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_pressure);
                holder.text_humidity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_humidity);
                holder.text_windspeed = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_wind);

                holder.weather_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_weather_view);;

                // store view holder
                convertView.setTag(holder);             

                convertView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                convertView.buildDrawingCache();

            }                               

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }

        // set view data

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: post your code used in the adapter for the gallery. You might not be re-using the view correctly

Comment: having a similar problem, but it surfaces as an outofmemory error since the Gallery for some reason is not able to free up the memory when there is a scrollview (or textview is scrollable). There is a known bug in the Gallery component that it doesn't allow for adapter view reuse at all (convertView is always null)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at a tutorial for Adapters and ConvertView.